# Perl, наличие символов кириллицы в тексте

Tags: perl, кириллица

Есть файл в кодировке UTF-8, содержащий строки на русском, английском и всякий мусор. Надо вывести только строки, в которых есть русские буквы. Вот это не работает:

```
use utf 8;

#... Тут в цикле каждую строку кидаю в $s_str ...
if ($s_str =~ /[А-Я,а-я]/)
{
    print($s_str);
}
```

**Решено добавлением в начало скрипта:**

```
use open qw(:utf8);
binmode(STDIN,':utf8');
binmode(STDOUT,':utf8');
```

Comment: Попробуйте `use open qw(:utf8);` и возможно придется делать `binmode(STDIN,':utf8');` ну или для того дескриптора через который вы файл читаете.

Comment: С этим работает, но несмотря на `binmode(STDIN,':utf8');` ругается каждый раз `Wide character in print at...`

Comment: Раз wide in print - то `binmode(STDOUT,':utf8');`

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl'у надо явно сообщить, что вы будете работать с файлами в кодировке UTF-8. На некоторых системах он сам это знает из текущих переменных окружения. Но лучше перестраховаться и задать:

```
use open qw(:utf8);      # считать открываемые файлы в кодировке utf-8
binmode(STDOUT,':utf8'); # при выводе на консоль так же использовать utf-8
```

Comment: Про `binmode(STDOUT,':utf8');` не знал, теперь все работает.